# Any first-order theory can be interpreted in an extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

Let $T$ be a recursively axiomatizable consistent theory formulated in classical first-order logic and assume $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent.

Does there always exist a recursively axiomatizable consistent extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in which T is interpretable?

It is well known that almost all of recursively axiomatizable consistent first-order theories can be interpreted in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ or its recursively axiomatizable consistent extension.

Some first-order theories such as Presburger arithmetic or $\mathsf{RCF}$ are complete and then there is no consistent essential extension of them, on the other hand some first-order theories satisfying some conditions such a $\mathsf{ZFC}$ have infinitely many recursively axiomatizable consistent essential extensions according to Gödel's first incompleteness theorem.

Then, I wonder if the proof theoretic powers of all of the recursively axiomatizable consistent extensions of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ are bounded or not in the class of all recursively axiomatizable consistent first-order theories.

In more general, some theories in other logical system such as higher-order logic or type system can be, in a sense, interpreted in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ or its recursively axiomatizable consistent extension. But here I restrict to first-order theories for the notion of interpretability to be clear.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

I think Asaf's comment resolves my question.

Any first-order theory that be able to prove completeness theorem, and define provability and then consistency can build a model of any recursively axiomatizable first-order theory $\mathsf{T}$ therefore interpret $\mathsf{T}$ with the added assumption $\mathsf{Con(T)}$.

I should have resolved this by myself. But, my understanding about the notion of interpretability seems insufficient in a basic level.

Thank you for all comennts!

Comment: $\sf ZFC+\operatorname{Con}(T)$?

Comment: @Asaf The question is more subtle because the OP asked the interpretation of $T$ into an extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. The question did not clarify the meaning of an interpretation, but if we follow what Hamkins used in his works (e.g., [this work](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.05262)) then the OP requires a kind of definability requirement. However, the question is stated ambiguously, so the OP apparently did not distinguish the consistency strength and interpretative power.

Comment: @HanulJeon: You can just take the first model of $T$ with respect to the canonical well-order on $L$.

Comment: That said, to conclude that $\sf ZFC+\operatorname{Con}(T)$ is consistent you would need stronger hypotheses than the ones stated in the question (for instance, if T is ZFC itself, the stated hypotheses are just that ZFC is consistent, which is weaker than the consistency of $\sf ZFC+\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$).

Comment: @Asaf $\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$ can prove the completeness theorem, and then say the existence of model for $T$. Fix any such model, we seem to be able to find formula that represents the domain of T and other Predicates of T and so on. But does this work at all ? All of interpreted axioms(in general, may be containing axiom schema) of T are proved in $\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$ ?

Comment: @Hanul I'm sorry for that ambiguity. I mean "Interpretability in theories" in the paper by Hamkins you mentioned but not mean consistency strength.

Comment: @Eric Aren't the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and of $\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$ equivalent If we use metatheory that can prove Godel's 2nd incompleteness theorem ?

Comment: @EricWofsey Good point, what about turning your comment into an answer?

Comment: I'm sorry. In general the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$ are not equivalent. I was confused of $\mathsf{Con(ZFC)}$ with the Godel sentence $G_{\mathsf{ZFC}}$ used in the 1st incompleteness theorem. I was terribly confused.